# Glitchy text animation in jQuery

Tags: jquery, animation, text, visual-glitch

I have text links which change colour on `hover` with CSS and shift left with jQuery.

Most of the time it works fine, but when the text begins with a capital "A", say, it leaves a weird trail behind the text character. This happens in webkit broswers (but not Firefox).

[You can see it in action with this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CDXMf/1/)

Is there any way to get rid of this glitch?

Comment: Just a note couldn't get the animate to work in IE 9 compatibility mode.

Comment: Seems like the italics causes it for me. Removing it also removed the artifacts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

wow, my first feeling was right: add a small padding to the sides and it work fine:
http://jsfiddle.net/k3vnd/1/

Not sure how to explain it, just reminds bugs from programming background. I think it's internal webkit issue.

Comment: For some reason it only works with a padding of 2px or more; 1px doesn't do the trick...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why it does that, but putting a small amount of padding around the link seems to solve the issue:

```
.links {

    position:absolute;
    left:20px;
    margin-top:25px;
    font-size:16.5pt;
    font-family: Garamond, Palatino, sans serif;
    font-style:italic;
    padding: 1px;    /* <=== added this line */

}​
```

See it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/LvT2h/

Comment: doesn't work in Safari 5. Still got the beginning line on the A

Comment: Yeah, I still get the problem in Chrome and Safari

Comment: Odd, in my Chrome it worked with 1px.  Perhaps it depends upon the exact font selected/rendered.